# How to avoid the warning 1352 in xc8 compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, pic, microchip, xc8

I used this macro in the xc8 compiler from microchip:

```
#define Unlock()  \
          do { \
              asm("BANKSEL PPSLOCK");   \
              asm("MOVLB   PPSLOCK");   \
              asm("MOVLW   0x55");      \
              asm("MOVWF   PPSLOCK");   \
              asm("MOVLW   0xAA");      \
              asm("MOVWF   PPSLOCK");   \
              asm("BCF     PPSLOCK,0"); \
          } while (0)
```

This is a special sequence mentioned in the datasheet to unlock the peripherial pin selection.
And always get these warnings:

```
../_main.c:437: warning: (1352) truncation of operand value (0xea0) to 8 bits
../_main.c:437: warning: (1352) truncation of operand value (0xea0) to 8 bits
../_main.c:440: warning: (1352) truncation of operand value (0xea0) to 4 bits
```

`0xEA0` is the adress of the `PPSLOCK` register, but I didn't see anything to truncate I just write 8 Bit values in an 8 Bit SFR.

Comment: Not familiar with xc8, but I am missing an indirection, fetching a byte _from/to_ the address PPSLOCK. `(PPSLOCK)` or whatever.

Comment: @Joop Eggen The address of `PPSLOCK`is defined with all other SFR in a header file. It's something like: `extern volatile unsigned char   PPSLOCK @ 0xEA0`

Comment: `unsigned char *PPSLOCK`? (I am talking totally out of my current area of competence.)

Comment: no just `unsigned char PPSLOCK`

Answer (score 0):

The `MOVWF` operation takes just 7 bits of the address operand, and you give it 12 bits. That's why you have to select the bank beforehand.